# Add pair of keys and values to dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

[image]

I'm trying to format the input format above into a list of dicts.

Basically what I want is to convert the contents of the file into a list of dicts. However, everytime I run the code I get the same output: [{'Similar: similar5, 'Score' : score5, 'Compound': smi}]. Which means only one dict was created, when my objective is to create 5 dicts (one for each line).
Can somebody help me fix this?

```
dt = [] # Creates a list to store dicts
with open('sample_text.out') as f: # Opens the target text file
    for line in f:

        if line.startswith('Compound'):
            smi = line.split()[1]
            dt.append({'Compound' : smi}) # Add smi as a value in a dict inside the list 'dt'

        else: # This part will iterate over the next few lines, split them and add them to the growing list of dicts

            new_line = line.split()
            similar = new_line[0]
            score = new_line[1]
            print new_line
            for dicts in dt:
                dicts['Similar'] = similar
                dicts['Score'] = score


print dt
```

Comment: At what point were you expecting this code to create a second dict? (What was `for dicts in dt: dicts['teste'] = new_line` intended to do?)

Comment: The only part of this code that creates a dict is `{'Compound' : smi}`, which only executes for lines starting with `'Compound'`.

Comment: What I really want is to create 5 dicts (one for each line). But I'm not getting it right.

Comment: I thought for dicts in dt: dicts['teste'] = new_line would update the dict created previously.

Comment: Might help if you add a sample input file, and the data structure you expect to see.

Comment: @MarcosSantana: It does. (It actually attempts to update *all* dicts created previously, but there's only one.) It *doesn't* make any new dicts.

Comment: I see. But why is it only creating one dict (in this case the last one)?

Comment: You loop over all the dicts in `dt`. There is only one, you never create any more. So you are updating the same dict each time. You need to create a new dict on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attempts to fix some of the design flaws in your code and output what you desire:

```
dictionaries = [] # Creates a list to store dicts

with open('sample_text.out') as input_file:  # Opens the target text file

    compound = None

    for line in input_file:

        if line.startswith('Compound'):
            _, smi = line.split()
            compound = smi
        else:
            similar, score = line.split()
            dictionaries.append({'Similar': similar, 'Score': score})
            dictionaries[-1]['Compound'] = compound

print(dictionaries)
```

Comment: Thank you cdlane! The output is fine. However I didnt understand the line _, smi = line.split(). Why can't I write smi = line.split()?

Comment: @MarcosSantana, you had `smi = line.split()[1]` which is fine, I just did a transformation to `_, smi = line.split()` -- in both cases two things are expected from the split and we only want the second.  Either works, I just tend to avoid numbers whenever possible.